# Facebook Login Capability for Website

Tags: facebook, authentication, integration

I have a website built heavily with HTML/Javascript running on Tomcat. This is a social platform in which users record and share videos. I already have a dedicated user sign-up mechanism but also want to add Facebooklogin capability.

The flow should be :

1. When a new user arrives  to my website, I check to see if this user is connected to Facebook.
2. If the user is connected to Facebook I login them to their account.
3. So I need to add them to my database when they first use Facebook credentials.
4. I guess I add them to my database with facebook_id number.

I searched some and it looks like it can be done with a server-side programming language such as PHP.

- What kind of user sign-up and log-in
  approach should I follow. There are
  several different implementations
  around.
- Is PHP my only option to implement
  it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but try looking at this:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

This integrates with the [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/), which lets you get the user's information with the correct oAuth scopes. With this, you could get their ID, and then figure out how to get it into your database.

Hope this helps! :) (If this isn't the answer you want, clarify a bit more.)